# in python wants to take certain part from a given string

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have a string type URL --https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vBiwyAL3OZ9VVCWCn5t6BagvLQoMjk82/view?usp=sharing
I want only part after "d/" and before "/view" from the above string so how can I use it using regex or any other function  example I only want 1vBiwyAL3OZ9VVCWCn5t6BagvLQoMjk82 from the above string using python. now I am using this
a =df['image']
for i in a :
print(type(i))

```
res=re.findall('/d/(.*)/view', i)
print(res)
```

but getting blank array res while printing it

Comment: *"I want"* is not how questions are supposed to be asked. You've described a task, not a problem

Answer (score 1):

I guess `/d/(.*)/view` is the regex you are looking for. `re.findall('/d/(.*)/view', url)[0]` works with your example.

```py
import re
s="--https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vBiwyAL3OZ9VVCWCn5t6BagvLQoMjk82/view?usp=sharing"
res=re.findall('/d/(.*)/view', s)
if len(res)==0:
    print('bad url')
else:
    print(res[0])
```

ADDITION (example using dataframes)

```py
import pandas as pd
import re
df=pd.DataFrame([["url1", "--https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vBiwyAL3OZ9VVCWCn5t6BagvLQoMjk82/view?usp=sharing"], ["url2", "--https://drive.google.com/file/d/second/one/view?usp=sharing"], ["noUrl", "anotherstring"]], columns=['name', 'image'])
```

[image: df is this dataframe]

Then

```py
for i in df['image']:
    res=re.findall('/d/(.*)/view', i)
    print(res)
```

output

```
['1vBiwyAL3OZ9VVCWCn5t6BagvLQoMjk82']
['second/one']
[]
```

as expected. A `len(res)=1` array whose `res[0]` element is the pattern you want if it matches, or an empty array if not.
If you have more than one /d/.../view patter in your url, then you may even have a longer than 1 answer. But empty one is only if you don't have a `.../d/.../view...` form

Comment: but it woking properly when using for a single string but getting blank result while using in for loop  --- a =df['image']
print(a)
for i in a :
    print(type(i))
    res=re.findall('/d/(.*)/view', i)
    print(res)

Comment: Not sure I understand the remark. It should work exactly the same in a for loop. If i is a string containing the pattern, then res is the part you want.

Comment: I even just tried it with a pandas dataframe (just to be sure it wasn't a type problem) and it works fine.

Comment: See my example in addition to my post

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize str.split method.
First split the string using "/d/" and then use  second part and split based on "/view". Take the first part of the new string.

```
html.split("/d/")[1].split("/view")[0]
```

Answer (score -1):

If your string is always going to look like this, I would break the string apart using the "/" as a delimiter.

```
s = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vBiwyAL3OZ9VVCWCn5t6BagvLQoMjk82/view?usp=sharing"
s = s.split('/')[5]
```